# How can I decode DVB-S2 packets with Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector, dvb

Searching for information on DVB-S2 BBframe structure I went into this wiki: http://wiki.wireshark.org/DVB-S2

Wireshark seems to decode this kind of data.
I'm using Wireshark 1.8.2 on ubuntu 12.04 - and everithing seems to be fine.
But I've downloaded the capture file and WS cannot recognise the DVB packets in the UDP payload.

I tried to inform it manually by "right click > decode as" in a packet, but there's no DVB protocol available to select.

It seems then I need to install the dissector informed on the wiki - but where can I get it and how can I install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DVB-S2 dissector has not yet been included in Wireshark releases(not even the development releases), however it should be available in a future release since I can see the dissector code in the trunk. [See this question for more.](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/16246/dvb-s2-dissector-missing-in-183)

I'm able to dissect DVB-B2 packets using my local Wireshark build. So if you need this feature *right away*, I guess the best option for now would be downloading the source and using a local Wireshark build for your purposes.

Comment: Works in ver. 1.10.6 (v1.10.6 from master-1.10).